# Using brace-init for a non-trivial multi-variable class

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, initializer-list, curly-braces

I am trying to make a certain template class brace-initializable, e.g.

```
template<typename T>
class A {
    private:
        std::vector<T> _data;
        std::size_t _m;
        std::size_t _n;

    public:
        Matrix(std::size_t m, std::size_t n, const T &fill); // regular (non-trivial) constructor
        Matrix(std::initializer_list<T> list);
};
```

However, I'm having trouble coming up with the implementation. I want to be able to do:

```
A<int> a = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, 2, 2};
// or something similar...e.g. C++11 style brace-init
A<int> a {{1, 2, 3, 4}, 2, 2};
```

I've tried:

```
template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(std::initializer_list<T> list)
    : _data(*list.begin()),
      _m(*(list.begin() + 1)),
      _n(*(list.begin() + 2)) {}
```

But that doesn't work for me. Help!

Comment: `Matrix(std::initializer_list<T> list, std::size_t m, std::size_t n);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to convert from an initializer_list to a vector you may copy all the elements.
STL makes this pretty nice with the begin/end iterators. Here's all the possible [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for vector

```
    Matrix(std::initializer_list<T> list, std::size_t m, std::size_t n)
    : _data(list.begin(), list.end()) // This is what might help
    , _m(m)
    ,_n(n)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Wow, you are a genius. Never thought that you could have extra parameters after the list. I don't know why; it makes perfect sense. Thanks!